# C# change windows UAC level to Always Notify

Tags: c#, registry, uac

I want to change the UAC level of the machine to "Always Notify" level which is the top level.

I tried changing the following registry key value to 1.
Key = `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

```
const string UACkey = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System";
            const string Subkey = "EnableLUA";
RegistryUtilities.SetValue(UACkey, Subkey, **1**, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord, RegistryUtilities.WOW64Key.Key64);
```

This result in UAC to be in 3rd level (Notify when programms try to make changes).

How to set it to top level?

Comment: This may sound a little accusatory, but I hope you aren't doing this without the user's permission...

Comment: this runs within only a lab, no harm for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find this by changing UAC and having regedit open at the same time, and watching which values changed.

When on the top setting, the value

```
ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin
```

changes to `2`, rather than `5` when it's on the 3rd level (nice logic there Microsoft). Changing that value as well as `EnableLUA` should do it.

Hope this helps